# ag-grid column headers will not resize by dragging

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-angular

I have copied the code column definitions and all attributes pertaining to resizing columns from the ag-grid examples for re-sizing columns in ag-grid vue, however I cannot resize my columns... the cursor will not even change to the "arrow" when I hover over the left or right edges of the columns.
Has anyone ever run into this?

Comment: welcome to [so], would you mind sharing your code on plunk or stackblitz so that others can help you? also go through how to create [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ag-grid version `19.1.2` you can enable column resizing by setting   `[enableColResize]=true` to ag-grid component